# PHP date format issue using strtotime()

Tags: php, json, date, strtotime

I am using

```
$jsdate = date("Y, m, d", strtotime('-1 month', (strtotime($date))));
```

to convert my dates from

```
2011-03-28
to
2011, 02, 28
```

Problem is this is producing unpredictable results. For example today I got

```
2011-03-28
converted to
2011, 02, 28  // OK

 AND

2011-03-29
to
2011, 03, 01 // not OK!
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here? I wonder if the calculation is inaccurate because of the `-1 month`.

Is there a way of simply subtracting `1` from `m` in `...date("Y, m, d", ...`?

MORE INFO:

My data needs to be formatted as `JavaScript Date Object` in which January is 0, Feb is 1, etc. Therefore there is not a need to specifically **subtract 1 month** but actually **subtract 1 from the month integer**. At the end, the resulting string is not supposed to be 1 month earlier, but actually the same date, represented using `JS Date Object` style. I believe @vprimachenko's answer below is a good solution. I apologize if this wasn't clear in my OP.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem has to do with when you subtract a month, you put it at 2011-02-29 which does not exist (feb 29th only exists in leap years - every 4 years). So date() is automatically translating it to March 1st.

Comment: @crayon - that makes sense - how do I fix this? as above, I would simply need to subtract `1` as an integer from `m`

Comment: hmm...well IMO this isn't really broken.  "-1 month" happens to land on a day that doesn't exist. The next day is the 1st.  That IS "-1 month".  If you made it land on 02-28 instead, that's technically more than 1 month.  You *could* instead use "-X days" to get it to place it on 02-28 but this is a matter of opinion (semantics), since not all months have the same amount of days. IOW to say "one month ago from today" is not exact time.  To say "02-01" is 1 month ago from "03-01" ...that is to say, "1 month ago" = X days... X is not going to be same from month to month.

Comment: If the first of March is not acceptable for one month before March 29th, what **is** acceptable?

Comment: please see my update in OP - I do not need the new date to be one month earlier - only subtract `1` from `month`. thanks for pitching in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might use

```
$datee = explode('-',$date);
if($datee[1]-- < 0) {
    $datee[1]=12;
    $datee[0]--;
}
$jsdate = implode(', ',$datee);
```

Comment: this solves the issue, because `explode` allow to simply subtract `1` from the month `[1]` -- thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

strtotime might work in an unexpected way but it is logical

```
strtotime('-1 months',strtotime('2011-03-29')  // is 2011-02-29
date('Y-m-d','2011-02-29'); //gets converted to the next real date
```

Here is one kind of fix
http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/fixing-strtotime-1-month/

Comment: that seems right - do you have any suggestion to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation isn't inaccurate, per se. There is no 2/29/2011. If you change your input to 3/29/2012, you'll see that it returns 2/29/2012, because 2012 is a leap year. The same would happen with using something like 7/31/2011. June only has 30 days, so July 31 minus one month would be July 1 (because June 31 doesn't exist).

You could just extract the month, subtract 1, and remake the date, but that will result in attempting to make dates that don't exist.

If you really need the corresponding day of the prior month, you'll probably need to do an if statement of something along the lines of the following to make the day roll back to the last day of February:

```
$jsdate = date("Y, m, d", strtotime('-1 month', (strtotime($date))));
if($month == '3') {
   $jsdate = date("Y, m, d", strtotime('-1 day', (strtotime($jsdate))));
}
```

You'll also have to account for the rest of the days in March that February doesn't have, as well as leap years, and do something similar for 31-day months that follow 30-day months.

Comment: thanks @shauna -- please see my update on OP for clarification of what I needed